# Nginx changing path on refresh

Tags: reactjs, image, nginx

I've got a directory of images for my site: `/var/www/project/images`. On the root page, my images are served fine. When I go to a new path `/auth`, the images load fine. When I refresh the page on `/auth`, I get 404s for my image file.

The request before a refresh shows `/var/www/project/images/image1.svg` after refresh shows `var/www/project/auth/images/image1.svg`. So it's taking the path and then adding the image path to the end, which doesn't exist.

Same behavior on clicking the browser "back" button.

Config below:

Excluded the port 80 stuff because I'll just copy the 443 to 80.

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    server_name my_server_name; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        root /var/www/project/
        index index.html;

        location /socket.io/ {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;

          proxy_pass http://socket/; # I have an upstream defined at top of file

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /images/ {
            try_files $uri $uri /var/www/project/images/;
            alias /var/www/project/images/;
            expires 10d;
        }
    }
```

Using React with Gatsby if that matters.

Comment: Did you run `sudo a2enmod`?

Comment: I'm running nginx